# shell command not working properly in my perl script

Tags: perl

i am having following command that works properly when i am running from the command prompt and i am able to get correct answer as follows

```
ನನ್ನ ಫೋಟೋ
ನನ್ನ ಸಂಪೂರ್ಣ ಪ್ರೊಫೈಲ್ ವೀಕ್ಷಿಸಿ
ಬ್ಲಾಗ್ ಆರ್ಕೈವ್
```

but it's giving wrong answer when I am trying to run the same command from browser

```
ನನ್ನ ಫೋಟೋ
ನನ್ನ ಸಂಪೂರ್ಣ ಪ್ರೊಫೈಲ್ ವೀಕ್ಷಿಸಿ
ಬ್ಲಾಗ್ ಆರ್ಕೈವ್
  *  ► 2014 (2)
  *  ► March (2)
```

My code is

```
system("grep '[ಅ-ಳ]' bemkikaddi.blogspot.in-result.txt > try4");
```

my try4 should only contain the kannada text how I can do this please help me.

Comment: Um, what command? `ನನ್ನ ಫೋಟೋ ನನ್ನ ಸಂಪೂರ್ಣ ಪ್ರೊಫೈಲ್ ವೀಕ್ಷಿಸಿ ಬ್ಲಾಗ್ ಆರ್ಕೈವ್` isn't really a command.

Comment: my command is [ system("grep '[ಅ-ಳ]' bemkikaddi.blogspot.in-result.txt > try4");]

Comment: i am having a text file of kannada corpus i need to remove all other text like english and special characters from file how i can do it

Answer (score 0):

Is your source code file UTF-8 encoded? Then you should include

```
 use utf8;
```

in your script to tell the Perl interpreter to treat your code as UTF-8 encoded text.

I had no idea you could use `grep` like that.

Comment: ok, finally i am having a text file of kannada corpus i need to remove all other text like english and special characters from file how i can do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you need. What do you mean by *"run the same command from browser"*?

This program takes the five strings of text you show and prints only the white space and Kannada characters. Is that close to your needs?

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my @text = (
  "ನನ್ನ ಫೋಟೋ\n",
  "ನನ್ನ ಸಂಪೂರ್ಣ ಪ್ರೊಫೈಲ್ ವೀಕ್ಷಿಸಿ\n",
  "ಬ್ಲಾಗ್ ಆರ್ಕೈವ್\n",
  "  *  ► 2014 (2)\n",
  "  *  ► March (2)\n",
);

for (@text) {
  print for /([\s\p{Kannada}]+)/g;
}
```

**output**

```
ನನ್ನ ಫೋಟೋ
ನನ್ನ ಸಂಪೂರ್ಣ ಪ್ರೊಫೈಲ್ ವೀಕ್ಷಿಸಿ
ಬ್ಲಾಗ್ ಆರ್ಕೈವ್
```